# How to configure Apache and OrientDB

Tags: apache-http-server, mamp

For some time I have been running MAMP and it has served me well. Now, however, I need to use OrientDB on my local machine for development purposes and I can't seem to be able to get the browser to connect to the server. I have to OrientDB server running and can access the Studio suite on the server port from my browser. Do I need to make any changes to my Apache configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB listens HTTP requests at port 2480 by default (unless is changed in orientdb-server-config.xml file). So to use it with Apache HTTPD create a proxy configuration entry in this way:

ProxyPass /orientdb http://localhost:2480/
ProxyPassReverse /orientdb http://localhost:2480/